# Local network speed between devices

Tags: ethernet

I have Raspberry Pi 3 B+ with IP 192.168.0.100 and Rock Pi 4 B with IP 192.168.0.200. Both in the same network connected to TP-Link 1043N V5 router. Both Pis have 1Gb Ethernet. However I am not able to use the whole bandwith even if it is not used elsewhere (only SSH on both to view tests).

What I get is:

Rock Pi receives data from Raspberry at 33.6MB/s and Raspberry receives data from Rock at 27.8MB/s.

I've made scripts to test that, both run either ways. Receive:

```
nc -l -p 3333 | pv -W > /dev/null
```

Send:

```
pv -B 1M /dev/zero | nc [other device's IP addr] 3333
```

What could be the problem here to achieve 1Gbps or 125MB/s?

Comment: Pi3B+ isn’t 1GB - it’s limited by usb 2.0 speed  https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/getting-gigabit-networking

Comment: @CoderMike that's sad. Seems like a need for an adapter.

Comment: Adapter connected to what? On the Pi you would still be limited to USB2 speeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Raspberry Pi organization publishes a [summary of the 3B+ here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b-plus/). If you look under the "Specifications" tab, you'll find the answer to your question:

> - Gigabit Ethernet over USB 2.0 (maximum throughput 300 Mbps)

There has been a lot written about this since the 3B+ was released. In addition to the link provided in one of the comments to your question, [this website has compiled some benchmarks](https://www.pidramble.com/wiki/benchmarks/networking), and you may find some of the information useful in comparison testing your 3B+. [In a similar question here on SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89325/10mb-s-speed-on-model-3-b-gigabit-ethernet), it's been pointed out that using SSH may slow things even further, suggests a "typical real-world" speeds and notes other demands on the USB may further reduce Ethernet throughput.